# Asterisk Does not work with PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos, asterisk

Good day.Due to requirement of VOIP calling over my own server i installed AsteriskNOW with FreePBX.All gone good until the point where i just unable to install the phpMyAdmin.Meanwhile during the installation i saw the asterisk installed some phpMyAdmin but the link http://myIpAddress/phpmyadmin will redirect to nowhere,saying file not found,meaning i guess the phpmyadmin wasn't installed at all.Anyway i am running server on CentOS and i do `yum install phpmyadmin` and it seems like to run,but every time i get this error

```
     Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.16-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-filter
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-filter
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
               php-filter
           Installed: php-common-5.3.28-3.shmz65.4.125.x86_64 (@anaconda-PBX-201403180405.x86_64/6.5)
               Not found
           Available: php-common-5.3.28-3.shmz65.4.119.x86_64 (pbx)
               Not found
           Available: php-common-5.3.28-3.shmz65.4.120.x86_64 (pbx)
               Not found
```

And so long it continues with heaps of line saying the same thing over and over that something not found.I have no clue what the heck is going on because seems like i am only one seeing this issue as in google there are purely NOTHING about this.Although i had no problem installing phpmyadmin WITHOUT asterisk.Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phpmyadmin is web interface to mysql.
It have no any relation to asterisk, asterisk can work without it, phpmyadmin work ok without asterisk.

In your output you can see that you have broken depency for php-filter.

Try install different package, for list of packages use

```
yum search php*filter
```